# using nohup with virtualbox in terminal in x

Tags: x11, virtualbox, nohup

When I start a VirtualBox virtual machine from a terminal within X, using  `nohup`, the virtual machine closes after I exit out of X. This is confirmed by both listing virtual machines, and looking at the running processes.

When I close the terminal, but stay in X, the virtual machine continues running as expected.

I'm assuming the issue is with either X, or my command using `nohup`. I've tried 2 variations on `nohup`, neither of which solves this issue:

```
(nohup vboxmanage startvm %s --type headless &) &
nohup vboxmanage startvm %s --type headless &
```

What needs to happen, to ensure a virtual machine continues to run after exiting the X window system?

I'm on Arch Linux, Bash shell, using the latest versions of everything.

Comment: Do you run X with startx? Using a display manager would log you out, and that would terminate VirtualBox, too.

Comment: Two ideas: 1) Try `setsid` instead of `nohup` 2) Try `VBoxHeadless` instead of `VBoxManage`